# vim: mapping a shortcut to save all files opened in tabs

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I have this in `~/.vimrc`:

```
noremap <C-s> :wa<CR>
```

Now, when I press `Ctrl-s`, it saves current file (tab) only. If files are modified in other tabs, it does NOT save them.

At the same time, when I manually run command `:wa`, this DOES save all the files.

Why the difference? And how can I ensure that all the files are written on shortcut?

Comment: Norepro, this works perfectly fine for me. What do you get when you run the command `noremap <C-s>` ?